# clean conversion of Index Signature (dictionary) to Map?

Tags: typescript, json.net

As of today, this is the only way I know how to convert `Dictionary<K,V>` (from, say, Json.NET) to `Map<K,V>` in TypeScript:

```
const json = '{ "1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three", "4": "four" }';
const dictionary = JSON.parse(json) as { [index: number]: string; };
const parsedMap = new Map<number, string>();
for (const i in dictionary) {
    if (!dictionary.hasOwnProperty(i)) { continue; }
    console.log(`dictionary[${i}]: ${dictionary[i]}`);
    parsedMap.set(parseInt(i, 10), dictionary[i]);
}
console.log(`parsedMap.size: ${parsedMap.size}`);
console.log(`parsedMap.get(4): ${parsedMap.get(4)}`);
```

Is there something already baked into something else that makes this conversion cleaner? Is this too verbose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment has [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
const parsedMap = new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(json)))
```

Note that this will have keys as strings, not numbers.

If you really need numbers, (or if you don't have `Object.entries()`),  it's slightly longer:

```
const dictionary = JSON.parse(json);
const parsedMap = new Map(Object.keys(dictionary).map(
     k => [parseInt(k, 10), dictionary[k]] as [number, string]
));
```

Comment: for the sake of typescript compilation: `.map(i => [+i, dictionary[+i]] as [number, string])`